# Git - Are you sure you pushed 'HEAD' there?

Tags: git

I am attempting to do `git request-pull origin/master fork` and I am getting the following output which I do not understand

```
warn: No match for commit 8eeec6ee3ddc483d54fa4eee1d89f8680020b0d9 found at fork
warn: Are you sure you pushed 'HEAD' there?
```

Can anyone explain to me what this means?

Here is the full output from the command

```
warn: No match for commit 8eeec6ee3ddc483d54fa4eee1d89f8680020b0d9 found at fork
warn: Are you sure you pushed 'HEAD' there?
The following changes since commit da72936f544fec5a335e66432610e4cef4430991:

  Git 2.24 (2019-11-04 13:33:06 +0900)

are available in the Git repository at:

  git@github.com:jeffreyroberts/git.git

for you to fetch changes up to 8eeec6ee3ddc483d54fa4eee1d89f8680020b0d9:

  Add line to new feature a (2019-11-08 01:53:03 -0500)

----------------------------------------------------------------
Jeffrey Roberts (9):
      Add line to travis ci config
      Add line to git ignore
      Merge remote-tracking branch 'fork/master'
      Add line to README.md
      Remove line from README.md
      Merge remote-tracking branch 'fork/master'
      Remove line from README.md
      Add new feature A
      Add line to new feature a

 .gitignore  | 1 +
 .travis.yml | 1 +
 README.md   | 2 --
 newFeatureA | 1 +
 4 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 newFeatureA
```

Comment: Did you `git push fork master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning means that the commit you're running request-pull for isn't on the remote server.  If you want someone to pull your changes, then your changes must necessarily be there to pull.  In this case, they're not, so Git is warning you.

If you push your changes to the remote server, such as by using `git push fork HEAD`, then the warning will go away.